# Email not sending from the server in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

brief desc....

I have a application that has a few different pages, one page sends the user a new password, and another page that creates a new account and sends the user their username, password and activation link and two pdfs...

Problem... When testing locally, from the two separate pages, both are working fine and sending emails as expected.

Now when  i have uploaded my application to the server, i test the same but only the new password email is sending to the user, and not the other email on the create new user page... Really strange.. i have tried the app on two different servers, again with the same outcome. only the password email sends to the user... It was working but then suddenly stopped working.. I don't understand why...

I have checked the smtp settings in iis and all is fine.. I just don't understand how it can send both email locally, but only one of the emails on the server? anybody have any incline of the issue.. ? here is my code...

```
 private void SendActivationEmail(string password, DataTable td)
        {
            try
            {
                string activationCode = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                this.InsertActivation.UpdateParameters["VendorName"].DefaultValue = this.DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
                this.InsertActivation.UpdateParameters["ActivationCode"].DefaultValue = activationCode;
                this.InsertActivation.Update();

                using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
                {
                    using (HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw))
                    {
                        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                        sb.Append("<table width='100%' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='2'>");
                        sb.Append(
                            "<tr><td align='center' style='background-color: #18B5F0' colspan = '2'><b>Congleton Vendor Declaration</b></td></tr>");
                        sb.Append("<tr><td colspan = '2'></td></tr>");
                        sb.Append("<tr><td><b>Company Name: </b>");
                        sb.Append(this.DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
                        sb.Append("</td><td><b>Date: </b>");
                        sb.Append(DateTime.Now);
                        sb.Append(" </td></tr>");
                        sb.Append(" </td></tr>");
                        sb.Append("<tr><td colspan = '2'><b></b> ");
                        sb.Append(td);
                        sb.Append("</td></tr>");
                        sb.Append("</table>");
                        sb.Append("<br />");
                        sb.Append("<table border = '1'>");
                        sb.Append("<tr>");
                        sb.Append(string.Empty);
                        foreach (DataColumn column in td.Columns)
                        {
                            sb.Append("<th style = 'background-color: #D20B0C;color:#ffffff'>");
                            sb.Append(column.ColumnName);
                            sb.Append("</th>");
                        }

                        sb.Append("</tr>");
                        foreach (DataRow row in td.Rows)
                        {
                            sb.Append("<tr>");
                            foreach (DataColumn column in td.Columns)
                            {
                                sb.Append("<td>");
                                sb.Append(row[column]);
                                sb.Append("</td>");
                            }

                            sb.Append("</tr>");
                        }

                        sb.Append("</table>");
                        StringReader sr = new StringReader(sb.ToString());
                        Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);
                        HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
                        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                        {
                            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, memoryStream);
                            pdfDoc.Open();
                            htmlparser.Parse(sr);
                            pdfDoc.Close();
                            byte[] bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
                            memoryStream.Close();
                            MailMessage mm = new MailMessage();
                            mm.To.Add(
                                new MailAddress(this.NewEmail.Text)); ////this needs to be changed to sourcing dept email
                            mm.From = new MailAddress(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DefaultEmail"]);
                            mm.Sender = new MailAddress(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DefaultEmail"]);
                            mm.Subject = "Account Activation";
                            string body =
                                "This is an automatically generated e-mail. Please do not reply to this message.";
                            body += "<br /><br />To";
                            body += "<br /><b>" + this.DropDownList1.Text.Trim() + ".</b>";
                            body +=
                                "<br /><br />In line with our digitilisation roadmap we are changing the process for our annual Country of Origin Declaration, "
                                + "this e-mail is the start of a more automated process which we hope you will find easier to use.";
                            body +=
                                "<br /><br />With this new process please ensure you have logged on and updated your information by"
                                + " <font color=\"red\">January 26th, 2019.</font> The link will not be available beyond this date.";

                            body += "<br /><br />Please keep your credentials safe";
                            body += "<br /><br />*****************************************";
                            body += "<br /><br />Username :  " + this.UserName + string.Empty;
                            body += "<br /><br />Password :  " + password + string.Empty;
                            body += "<br /><br />*****************************************";
                            body += "<br /><br />Please click the following link to activate your account";
                            body += "<br /><a href = '" + this.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Replace(
                                        "Congl/IndividualMail.aspx",
                                        "Activation.aspx?ActivationCode=" + activationCode) + "'>Declaration</a>";
                            body += "<br /><br />Should you have any issues please contact myself or Izzy beacham. ";
                            body += "<br />We would appreciate your feedback.";
                            body += "<br /><br />With Best Regards,";
                            body += "<br />Janet rinda";
                             body +=
                                "<br /> ";
                            body +=
                                "<br /><br />This communication contains information which is confidential and may also be privileged. It is for the exclusive use of the addressee. "
                                + "If you are not the addressee please note that any distribution, reproduction, copying, publication or use of this communication or the information is prohibited. If you have received this communication in error, please contact us immediately and also delete the communication from your computer.";
                            body +=
                                "<br /><br /><b>Important notice: This e-mail and any attachment thereof contain corporate proprietary information. "
                                + "If you have received it by mistake, please notify us immediately by reply e-mail and delete this e-mail and its attachments "
                                + "from your system. Thank you.</b>";
                            mm.Body = body;
                            mm.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(new MemoryStream(bytes), "Declaration.pdf"));
                            mm.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(this.Server.MapPath("~/VendorHelpPage.pdf")));
                            mm.IsBodyHtml = true;
                            SmtpClient smtClient = new SmtpClient();
                            smtClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                            try
                            {
                                smtClient.Send(mm);
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {
                                this.ErrMsg = App.App.HandleError(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod(), ex, string.Empty);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                this.ErrMsg = App.App.HandleError(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod(), ex, string.Empty);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors? I think the issue is with the PDF path, on server you did not have permission to save the pdf.

Comment: Don't throw away all the details in any Exceptions. Seeing the default report in the event log or even in a yellow screen of death will tell you exactly what is failing (assuming you are getting an exception).

Comment: Hey, no i am not getting any errors, its saying the email has sent, but its not sending anything.

Comment: Are you using any 3rd party email sending provider? Also can you try sending the email without PDF to make sure PDF file permission is not an issue.

Comment: Then check spam folder of the email, I think its going in span.

Comment: Right guys! thank you very much. Your recommendations made me remember a previous problem... The problem was that when i was publishing my app from VS.. it did not include my VendorHelpPage.pdf ... So i had to include this on my server version.. Anyway thank you very much for getting my brain back into gear :)

Comment: This was working before and what i have done is on the server, deleted all the files and then pasted all the new updated version. I should have just overwritten and my pdf that i previously added would not have dissapeared.